# How do I add an auto-populated form record (created from another record) to a table in access?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I am populating a form with information from two other forms to create a new client record. From form 1 I get the CaseID which will tie the new client record back to the Case table. Form 2 lets me select a client from a list and pull information for some fields into the new record. These data populate Form 3 which *appears* to show a new record (then number at the bottom of the form is 1 more than currently exists in the table) **But** the ClientID field is blank - this is the unique key for the client records table. I cannot seem to get this field to increment and thus can't get the record to save to the table.

Based on various searches I've tried forcing the record to save but nothing happens... no errors nor new records. I've tried

```
If me.dirty then
    me.dirty = false
end if
```

and

```
DoCmd.RunCommand acCmdSaveRecord
```

I assume I'm simply not truly initiating a new record even though the form suggests it is being created. What is the appropriate way to add the record, including which control I need to use to initiate the action (e.g., attach to the On_click() event of a button). Note that, sometimes the record will be perfectly fine as populated, and sometimes the user may need to edit one or more fields before saving the record. It is also plausible that occasionally a user will decide the record should not be added and thus will need to close without saving.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out that the ClientID field in the test database I was provided is NOT an autonumber field as it will be in the live dB version. So I simply had to look up the max value in the table and add one. I will have to test the autoincrement when I get the true Dev environment set up with the actual database structure duplicated instead of the mockup I have been working on to create the work flow.